# Where did http://java.sun.com/jsf/ go?

Tags: web-applications, jsf-2, java-ee-6

I'm just starting a JSF2.0 project and eclipse is giving me an error when it's trying to look up http://java.sun.com/jsf/html, http://java.sun.com/jsf/core, etc. I tried loading the URLs in a browser, but I get a giant "Sorry! We couldn't find your document." from Oracle.com Searching oracle.com didn't help much either. it produced one link on "Oracle*SaaS*Platform:*" when searching for 'jsf spec'. Can anyone offer a solution or suggest an alternative that can be used? I'm on Weblogic 10.3.4 and using PrimeFaces

Answer (score 2):

Those are  not URLs. They don't point to resources; they're just identifiers.

You are probably targeting a servlet container that doesn't implement the full Java EE web profile (e.g. Tomcat). You need to add your own implementation ([Mojarra](http://java.net/projects/mojarra/) or [MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org/)) or switch servers (e.g. Glassfish or JBoss).

Comment: Thank you for the expanded explanation. Could you elaborate some more? How would I add my own implementation? Please see original post for env details

Comment: WebLogic should already ship with a JSF implementation. Probably your Eclipse went mad. Check in project properties if *Target Runtime* is properly set to WebLogic.

Comment: @bakoyaro - BalusC is correct; Weblogic provides these libraries. As well as checking the target runtime, check the enabled [facets](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user/topics/cfacets.html) in your project properties.